# How to test javascript class using jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

trying to test class using jest its throwing declaration exception , what would be correct approach to test class in below scenario and test promise chain?

main.ts

```
export class ModuleExecutor {
    public execute(moduleName: string): (param1, param2) => any {
        const self = this;
        return function(params: any, responseCallback: (param: any, param2: any) => any) {
            let _mod;
            let _httpRequest;
            let _params;
            Promise.resolve(getApiModule(self.identity, moduleName))
                .then((mod: ModuleBase < any, any > ) => {
                    _mod = mod;
                    mod.ExecStage = ExecStage.Init;
                    // @ts-ignore - red squiggly for the return mismatch which are resolved in Grunt
                    return mod.init(getHttpModule(self.identity), params);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

main.spec.ts

```
  describe("Test promise chaining with Mock functions", () => {
        const myMockFuncExecute = jest.fn((mod: ModuleBase<any, any>) => {
            _mod = mod;
            _mod.ExecStage = ExecStage.Init;
            const ret = _mod.Init(getHttpModule(Identity.node), params);
            Promise.resolve(ret);
        });

        jest.mock("./main.ts");
        const executerClass = require("./main.ts");
        executerClass.mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                init: myMockFuncExecute
            };
        });

        it('it should get Modulebase', async () => {
            const _result = new executerClass(Identity.node);
            _result.execute("Payments/url").then(myMockFuncExecute())
            .then((module) => {
                const mod = module;
                expect(mod).toEqual(ModuleBase);
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: this is confusing. Why do you mock `./main.ts`, if it's the class you are testing? Looks like the only thing you'd mock is `getApiModule`. 
And what declaration exception does it throw?

Comment: @HermanStarikov its throwing unhandled promise rejection , can you give me example to show how i would mock getApiModule

Comment: what's the rejection reason?
I imagine you are importing getApiModule, so you would have to mock that module. And make the mock implementation to return an object that has an init method, kinda like the executerClass you have

Comment: Make sure to return your promise from the test, otherwise Jest won't wait for it